# OrientDB - OrientDB function not executing using Java

Tags: java, javascript, orientdb

I have a database with the following Javascript function. But when I try to execute the same function using Java, it doesn't work. [image]

And I'm trying to connect using this Java code:

```
ODatabaseDocumentTx db = new ODatabaseDocumentTx("remote:localhost/localDBDocumentAPI").open("admin", "admin");
OFunction func = db.getMetadata().getFunctionLibrary().getFunction("CreateLinks");
func.execute();
```

When I ran the Java code, it ran without any error though. But no results.

Comment: Could you elaborate on "it doesn't work"? Do you get an error message, an exception, nothing happens, something happens but not what you expected...?

Comment: @AJPerez Oh sorry. Nothing happens. So to check that i passed a invaild function name (function doesnt exist), it gave null pointer exception. So i think its obtaining that fuction but the execution doesnt happen. And it works when i try manually in orient db. It doesnt work only in Java

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
String URL = "remote:localhost/localDBDocumentAPI";
String functionName = "funfun";
try (ODatabaseDocumentTx db = new ODatabaseDocumentTx(URL)) {
    db.open("admin", "admin");
    OFunction f = new OFunction();
    f.setName(functionName);
    f.setLanguage("javascript");
    f.setParameters(new ArrayList());
    f.setCode("print(\"hellooo\\n\");");
    f.save();
}

try (ODatabaseDocumentTx db = new ODatabaseDocumentTx(URL)) {
    db.open("admin", "admin");
    OFunction f = db.getMetadata().getFunctionLibrary().getFunction(functionName);
    f.execute();
}

try (ODatabaseDocumentTx db = new ODatabaseDocumentTx(URL)) {
    db.open("admin", "admin");
    OFunction f = db.getMetadata().getFunctionLibrary().getFunction(functionName);
    db.command(new OCommandScript("javascript", f.getCode())).execute();
}
```

You can see that the first one is executed on client side, and the second on server side (which I believe it's your intent).
Although for this to work you have to change your **$ODB_HOME/orientdb-server-config.xml** to allow **javascript** to be run on server side.

Mine looks like this:

```
    <handler class="com.orientechnologies.orient.server.handler.OServerSideScriptInterpreter">
        <parameters>
            <parameter value="true" name="enabled"/>
            <parameter value="SQL" name="allowedLanguages"/>
            <parameter value="javascript" name="allowedLanguages"/>
        </parameters>
    </handler>
```

See [OrientDB note](http://orientdb.com/docs/last/orientdb.wiki/Javascript-Command.html#enable-server-side-scripting) about this.

Answer (score 0):

The above code should have worked.The same example has been given in [Orientdb doc](http://orientdb.com/docs/2.0/orientdb.wiki/Functions.html#usage-via-java-api) but couldn't work.

The one which worked :

```
ODatabaseDocumentTx db = new ODatabaseDocumentTx("remote:localhost/test").open("admin", "admin");
Integer result = db.command(new OCommandFunction("testfunc")).execute(1,2);
```

Function can be executed through the command.Its shown in above code.